# How to quickly print Ruby hashes in a table format?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

Is there a way to quickly print a ruby hash in a table format into a file? 
Such as:

```
keyA   keyB   keyC   ...
123    234    345
125           347
4456
...
```

where the values of the hash are arrays of different sizes. Or is using a double loop the only way?

Thanks

Comment: Easiest is a "double loop", but it's still a one-liner; is it so bad?

Comment: IMO it's too specialized to be a built-in feature, and too easy to do "by hand" :)

Comment: Wouldn't be bad for someone to post the easy one-liner.  :-)

Comment: (Might be 2-3 lines depending on how the different-sized arrays need to be handled :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a version of steenslag's that works when the arrays aren't the same size:

```
size = h.values.max_by { |a| a.length }.length
m    = h.values.map { |a| a += [nil] * (size - a.length) }.transpose.insert(0, h.keys)
```

`nil` seems like a reasonable placeholder for missing values but you can, of course, use whatever makes sense.

For example:

```
>> h = {:a => [1, 2, 3], :b => [4, 5, 6, 7, 8], :c => [9]}
>> size = h.values.max_by { |a| a.length }.length
>> m = h.values.map { |a| a += [nil] * (size - a.length) }.transpose.insert(0, h.keys)
=> [[:a, :b, :c], [1, 4, 9], [2, 5, nil], [3, 6, nil], [nil, 7, nil], [nil, 8, nil]]
>> m.each { |r| puts r.map { |x| x.nil?? '' : x }.inspect }
[:a, :b, :c]
[ 1,  4,  9]
[ 2,  5, ""]
[ 3,  6, ""]
["",  7, ""]
["",  8, ""]
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this gem I wrote (prints hashes, ruby objects, ActiveRecord objects in tables): http://github.com/arches/table_print

Comment: tp not working on a give hash, it works on an AR object. When I tried on a hash, I get this => table_print-1.0.1/lib/table_print/fingerprinter.rb:38:in `block in populate_row'

Comment: In general it does work on hashes. If it isn't working for you please open an issue at http://github.com/arches/table_print or email me about your problem (chris@arches.io)

Comment: error is gone after updating to the latest version, still its not the one am looking for, but for table thing, it looks the best one

Answer (score 3):

```
h = {:a => [1, 2, 3], :b => [4, 5, 6], :c => [7, 8, 9]}
p h.values.transpose.insert(0, h.keys)
# [[:a, :b, :c], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

Comment: Works as long as the arrays are the same length.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no built-in function. Here's a code that would format it as you want it:

```
data = { :keyA => [123, 125, 4456], :keyB => [234000], :keyC => [345, 347] }

length = data.values.max_by{ |v| v.length }.length

widths = {}
data.keys.each do |key|
  widths[key] = 5   # minimum column width

  # longest string len of values
  val_len = data[key].max_by{ |v| v.to_s.length }.to_s.length
  widths[key] = (val_len > widths[key]) ? val_len : widths[key]

  # length of key
  widths[key] = (key.to_s.length > widths[key]) ? key.to_s.length : widths[key]
end

result = ""
data.keys.each {|key| result += key.to_s.ljust(widths[key]) + " " }
result += "\n"

for i in 0.upto(length)
  data.keys.each { |key| result += data[key][i].to_s.ljust(widths[key]) + " " }
  result += "\n"
end

# TODO write result to file...
```

Any comments and edits to refine the answer are very welcome.